# Laravel Forge not honoring Craft 3 maxUploadFileSize config setting

Tags: craft3, config, php, upload, digitalocean

I have a Craft 3 site deployed to a Digital Ocean droplet via Laravel Forge. I have the `maxUploadFileSize` set to 256B (`268435456` in bytes) in my `config/general.php` like so:

```
<?php

return [
  // Global settings
  '*' => [
    'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
    'securityKey' => getenv('SECURITY_KEY'),
    'maxUploadFileSize'=> 268435456,
    'useProjectConfigFile' => true,
    'defaultSearchTermOptions' => array(
      'subLeft' => true,
      'subRight' => true,
    ),
  ],
  'dev' => [
    'devMode' => true,
    'rememberedUserSessionDuration' => 'P1Y',
    'userSessionDuration' => 'P1Y',
  ],
  'production' => [
    'allowAdminChanges' => false,
  ],
];
```

When I go to upload a file larger than 8mb I get this error:

> The file “.mp3” could not be uploaded, because it exceeds the maximum upload size of 8.0 MB.

My `php.ini` has `upload_max_filesize` set to `256M`. I can't figure out what exactly is blocking uploads. Nothing in my `.env` file or my `nginx.conf` appears to be hindering the upload size.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I did confirm that my `client_max_body_size` is set to `256M` in my `nginx.conf` file in Laravel Forge.

Answer (score 3):

After doing some digging, this article helped solve my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36582004/increase-upload-max-filesize-via-forge.

By increasing the `post_max_size` in the PHP FPM Configuration and the PHP CLI Configuration I was able to resolve the issue and increase my upload limit to `256M`.

Comment: Just a comment on this - using both this answer and Andrew's answer below it worked for me, but not until I restarted both PHP and nginx.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [nginx-craft](https://github.com/nystudio107/nginx-craft) specifically:

https://github.com/nystudio107/nginx-craft/blob/master/forge-example/NginxConfiguration.conf#L25

```
    # Disable limits on the maximum allowed size of the client request body
    client_max_body_size 0;
```

Setting `client_max_body_size` to `0` will set it to "no limit" so you can control any limit you like in one place, the Craft CMS `general.php` config file.